# Verificar que no exista duplicados antes de hacer INSERT

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Estoy programando en Visual Basic con base de datos en SQL Server, y no puedo hacer que al momento de insertar un nuevo registro en la base de datos no me deje hacerlo si se repiten las siguientes condiciones:

1. Que el registro no tenga el mismo número
2. Que el registro no tenga el mismo año
3. Que no tenga el mismo modelo

Por ejemplo, si introduzco un registro con los siguientes datos: 
`Numero: 1, Año:2017 y Modelo: A`. lo ingrese, pero que no lo ingrese si se vuelven a repetir todos los datos, a menos que uno de ellos cambie.. por ejemplo, que el número aun sea `1` y el modelo `A`, pero que el año sea `2018`, si lo ingrese.

Tengo el siguiente código, pro solo me funciona pra 1 condición, en este caso el número, pero no me sirve para impedir que se registre con las 3 condiciones (`numero`, `año` y `modelo`):

```
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registros WHERE numerodoc = '" & tbxNumDoc.Text & "''" 
Com = New SqlCommand(SQL, MiConexion) 
Rs = Com.ExecuteReader() Rs.Read() 
lblBuscaNumDoc.Text = Rs(0) 
Rs.Close() 
MiConexion.Close() 
If lblBuscaNumDoc.Text = 0 Then 
    conectar.sqlconecta() 
    conectar.creadocumento()
```

Comment: Que es lo que has hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: Tenia el siguiente codigo, pro solo m funciona pra 1 condicion, en ste caso el numero, pero no me sirve para impedir que se registre con las 3 condiciones (numero, año y modelo): SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registros WHERE numerodoc = '" & tbxNumDoc.Text & "''"
            Com = New SqlCommand(SQL, MiConexion)
            Rs = Com.ExecuteReader()
            Rs.Read()
            lblBuscaNumDoc.Text = Rs(0)  
            Rs.Close()
            MiConexion.Close()

            If lblBuscaNumDoc.Text = 0 Then
                conectar.sqlconecta()
                conectar.creadocumento()

Comment: Hola Pancho, bienvenido a [es.so], por esta ocasión he editado tu pregunta agregando los avances que has tenido, así como darle el formato adecuado, para futuras preguntas recuerda siempre poner todos los detalles importantes (avances, mensajes con errores etc.) para que esté más completa y sea más fácil de resolver para otros usuarios ;)

Answer (score 2):

Usa lo siguiente:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tabla WHERE Condiciones)
BEGIN
  -- Código de inserción
END
```

Esto comprueba si existe el registro, en caso de que no exista lo inserta
también prueba con `IF EXISTS`

Comment: Porque es el 1 despues del select?

Comment: Gracias por el aporte fue de mucha ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la sentencia if exist, como en el siguiente ejemplo,

```
IF  EXISTS( SELECT campo FROM tabla WHERE campo2 = 'condición')
BEGIN
delete from tabla where campo = (select campo from Forma where campo2 = 'condición')
      END
  insert ...
```

Y así no habrá duplicados, de ésta manera borras el registro anterior para poder insertar uno nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agregar las condiciones en tu consulta SQL para que se puedan cumplir los criterios:

```
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM registros WHERE numerodoc = @NumeroDoc AND Anio = @Anio AND Modelo = @Modelo

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numerodoc ", tbxNumDoc.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Anio", txtAnio.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modelo", txtModelo.text)

Rs = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
If Rs Is Nothing Then
Else
    'Aquí manejas las condiciones para realizar el INSERT
End If
```

Nota que he cambiado la forma de tu consulta, al tener consultas dinámicas es suceptible a Inyección SQL, para evitar esto, es necesario que parametrices la consulta o hagas uso de *Stored Procedures*.